# Nested subshell short-circuiting and set -e

Tags: bash

```
a) $> ( echo 0 ; ( echo 1 ; false ; echo 2 ) ; echo 3 )
0
1
2
3

b) $> ( echo 0 ; ( set -e ; echo 1 ; false ; echo 2 ) ; echo 3 )
0
1
3

c) $> ( set -e ; echo 0 ; ( echo 1 ; false ; echo 2 ) ; echo 3 )
0
1

d) $> ( set -e ; echo 0 ; ( set -e ; echo 1 ; false ; echo 2 ) ; echo 3 )
0
1

e) $> ( set -e ; echo 0 ; ( set -e ; echo 1 ; false ; echo 2 ) && echo ok ; echo 3 )
0
1
2
ok
3
```

I'm not following the last case, why do **exterior** (with respect to the inner-most subshell) `&&` disables inner-most `set -e` option? The previous cases are here to show that everything works as expected without `&&`

Are there any workarounds besides this?

```
$ ( set -e ; echo 0 ; ( { echo 1 && false && echo 2 ; } && echo ok ) || exit 1 ; echo 3 )
0
1
```

Comment: Let's not wander off into an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The workaround is to stop expecting that `set -e` will  behave in the way you want it to and to do your own error checking.

Comment: I think the reason here is that your inner `set -e` is redundant; subshells inherit a single global setting, so anything that disables it in the parent shell (here, the `&&`, per [Exception 2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)) disables it in the subshell as well.

Comment: But in any case, see [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).